# Content of Web not visible in google chrome, but is visible in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Suddenly, my web page content is not visible in chrome. It was showing day before yesterday, but when i checked my site today the content is not showing. When i inspect the code it shows the content is coming but not visible on page. Also if i open the site in firefox, the content is visible in it.

Can you guys suggest me why this is happening.

Comment: Can you show us some code for that?

Comment: Please send your code via jsfiddle.net..

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I found the solution. Its the issue of font family. Browser was not supporting that font family of page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. Its the issue with font-family. chrome was not supporting the font family of the page. I just changed the font family and now content is showing.

Comment: That's interesting, because if Chrome doesn't get what type of font you're using, then it should revert to the default `serif` fonts. Maybe you could have specified `@font-face` in your CSS files?

Comment: I was simply using font-family: Fira Sans; which was creating problem. I changes font-family and now everything is working fine.